# How to change y_axis format, while having percent change option?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Update: Changing percentual change for 'PL Acumulada' series
This is the new tooltip formatter:

```
hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
                 formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
                   "function(tooltip) {
                   function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                    col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
                    compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                    compVal2 = compVal
                    delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */ 
                    adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip (percentagem)*/
                    y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                    return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                   }
                   
                   function pref2(pts) {
                   col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
                    compVal = compVal2
                    delta =  y/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */ 
                    adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip (percentagem)*/
                    y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                    return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                   }
                   
    
                    xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                    ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (AUM)*/
                    ttd2 = pref2(this.points[1]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (CUM NP)*/
                    return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                 /* send tooltip formatting (DATE, AUM, CUM NP*/
                   }")
      ) %>%
```

[image]

As you can see, 24 657 / 49 036 799 (first value in view of 'AUM' line) *100% = 0.05%

################################ Original question #############

I have two datasets: data and data2. Both of these have two columns (one has dates and the other has values).

Datasets:

```
data <- structure(list(DATA = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                         19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                         19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), AUM = c(32962594L, 
                                                                                               33213220L, 33278745L, 33482196L, 33591402L, 33591402L, 33660796L, 
                                                                                               33810382L, 34172853L, 34264748L, 34032274L, 34216610L, 34416588L, 
                                                                                               34462226L, 35308681L, 35429483L, 35456650L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           -17L), class = "data.frame")

data2 <- structure(list(DATA = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                          19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                          19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), CUM_SUM = c(0L, 
                                                                                                    173080L, 318158L, 504538L, 607304L, 607304L, 771404L, 916984L, 
                                                                                                    1153354L, 1292314L, 1381434L, 1708534L, 1937284L, 2035272L, 2817863L, 
                                                                                                    3046949L, 3046949L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to present a graph that not only shows the values progression, but also, for every point, indicates the % change to the first value. I also want the y_axis to be the points values and not the % change.
My present graph shows for one series (data) the % change, but the y_axis is not in the desired format. Instead of the % changes, I want to see the values.

This is my graph code:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "data"), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "data2"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "data", yAxis = 0, id = "data_line", data = data, hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM), type = 'line', compare = 'percent') %>%
  hc_add_series(name = 'data2', yAxis = 1, id = 'data2_line', data = data2, hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), type = 'line') %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#990000")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change} %)<br/>',
             split = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

And this is the graph that results from the code:

[image]

As you can see, the left y_axis is not in the desired format.

Comment: I just want to clarify that I understand your code at this point. Your data 2 is the cumulative sum, but that's not how `compare` works. Highcharts `compare` compares the value with the first value in the _view_. So if you zoom into a specific range, all of your % values change. Did you already know that it's not cumulative? I just wanted to make sure. Additionally, if you plot both lines, where the right is percentages and the left is $, you'll end up with something closer to two flat lines unless you really skew the ranges. Is that also something you're looking for?

Comment: @Kat, thank you for your help. Yes, my data2 is the cumulative sum. But it is not the cumulative sum of data. It is the cumulative sum of another variable that is irrelevant for the case. I know that 'compare' compares the value with the first in the view and it is quite different from cumulative sum. Both variables (AUM and PL Acumulada) are in the same measurement. But when I use Highcarts compare option, the variable´s values are transformed into percentages. And I dont want that. Just want to have the information (the % change) available in the tooltip. Dont want to have my y_axis changed

Comment: @Kat , is it possible to change the code so that the percentual change of the 'PL Acumulada' line is in order of the first value of the variable 'AUM'?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. Could you try explaining a bit more about what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, of course. So, the tooltip shows the percentual change for each line: it takes the first value in view (compVal) and calculates the percentual change (delta). Since we have two series ('AUM' and 'PL Acumulada'), compVal assumes two different values, one for each serie. What I would like to have is the percentual change of the series 'PL Acumulada' in relation to the first value in view of the serie 'AUM'. Therefore, compVal would be always the first value in view of 'AUM'

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly, you want to change the order of the items in the tooltip. Is that correct? If so, is it that you want to switch the order?

Comment: No no. For each point of each line, the codes calculates the percentual change: this value is obtained by delta and it is equal to that point minus the first value in view, divided by the first value in view. This first value in view is obtained by the variable compVal. Naturally, each line/series has a different compVal. For the series 'AUM' everything is good.

Comment: What I want to change is the percentual change of the 'PL ACUMULADA' line. Instead of being calculated in the same manner as in the line 'AUM', the percentual change should be equal to each point of the series divided by the first value in view of the series 'AUM'

Comment: I will update my question with a possible, but I think not optimal, way of obtaining what I looking for

Comment: You changed everything about your question and my answer doesn't even make sense, If you needed something like this, it's important to ask another question. Remember, the Q&A isn't just for you, it's for anyone with questions. I'll take a look at your question, but you really need to make it a new question. (I can 'one click' this question back to what you had originally written, but I don't want to do that without your input.)

Comment: @Kat, I will write another question then. Thank you

Comment: @Kat, can you see the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006507/r-highchart-percent-change-with-two-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Update: Ensuring that Hidden Trace Remains Hidden (Legend Click Event)

One option is removing the legend click event, which seems counterintuitive. Control is one of the many things that make these charts useful. Instead, I've modified the click event for the trace that is linked to the hidden trace. Check it out.

Now when you click the `Data Values ($)` item in the legend, it essentially *ignores* the `legendItemClick` event and updates the visibility independently.

```
#----------------- with modified number formatting &&& SPLIT tooltips ------------------
# added an event to ensure visibility doesn't change on invisible series
highchart() %>%  # three y-axes with min/max scaling
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = F, id = 'dv',
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM),
                events = list(
                  legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
                    "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
                  ))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'dv', visible = F, # <-- linked & invisible!
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data2, type = "line", name = "Data2", compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "Data Values ($)"), opposite = F),
                     list(title = list(text = "Data2"), opposite = T)) %>% 
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#336600","#990000")) %>% # added first color 2x for invisible axis
  hc_tooltip(split = T,
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(tooltip) {
      function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
        if(nm != 'Data2'){
          compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
          delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */   
          adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
        } else {     
          adder = '';                         /* if data2, there are no calculations to add */
        }
        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
      }
      xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
      ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
      ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
      return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                 /* send tooltip formatting */
      }")) %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime")
```

##### Update: Custom Format Values & Splitting Tooltips

In comments, I wrote that you could replace the `y` declaration in the JavaScript with `y = Highcharts.numberFormat`<s>`ter`</s>`(this.y,  0, '.', ' ');`

There are a few things wrong here. First, it's `Highcharts.numberFormat` <- (no `ter` at the end). Sorry about that. If that's all it was, I would have added another comment. However, that leads to a few other issues that I didn't account for with that not-great bit of information. So to rectify that and to address your other comment about splitting the tooltips, I've added the following information.

Here's the plot I provided originally, without split tooltips but *with* formatted values. I've changed 3: things. `y`, `delta`, and how `y` is called in the string `tooltip`.

In `delta`, I've changed `y` to `this.y`. (The line immediately following `y = Highcharts...` is the line that creates `delta`.)

In `tooltip`, I've removed `toFixed()` from `${y}`.

```
#----------------- with modified number formatting ------------------
highchart() %>%  # three y-axes with min/max scaling
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = F, id = 'dv',
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'dv', visible = F, # <-- linked & invisible!
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data2, type = "line", name = "Data2", compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "Data Values ($)"), opposite = F),
                     list(title = list(text = "Data2"), opposite = T)) %>% 
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#336600","#990000")) %>% # added first color 2 times to account for invisible axes
  hc_tooltip(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(tooltip) {
          /* collect name, x (and format it), y, color, compare value, and % difference */
      nm = this.series.name;
      if(nm == 'Data2') {    /* use standard tooltip for data2 */
       return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
      }
      xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* collect/format date */
      compVal = this.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue; /* 1st val in view */
      col = this.color;                                      /* set color and y to vars */
      y = Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, '.', ' ');    /*   <<---- I'm new!!   */
      delta = (this.y - compVal)/compVal * 100; /* compute the comparison value as HC does */   
      tooltip = `<span>${xform}<br><hr><b><span style='color:${col};'>`; /* create tooltip */
      tooltip += `● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} (${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;
      return tooltip; /* send back new tooltip */
      }")) %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime")
```

[image]

###### Splitting the Tooltips

If you follow the JavaScript, when the tooltips are not split, you see that one string was returned. This string was created using multiple variables preceded by `this`.

When you split the tooltips, each plotted trace has an index in `this.points`. Additionally, you need to return a string for each item in the split. In your graph, you have 1 x-axis item and 2 y-axis items, so you need to return 3 strings.

```
#----------------- with modified number formatting &&& SPLIT tooltips ------------------
highchart() %>%  # three y-axes with min/max scaling
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = F, id = 'dv',
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'dv', visible = F, # <-- linked & invisible!
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data2, type = "line", name = "Data2", compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "Data Values ($)"), opposite = F),
                     list(title = list(text = "Data2"), opposite = T)) %>% 
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#336600","#990000")) %>% # added first color 2 times to account for invisible axes
  hc_tooltip(split = T,
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(tooltip) {
      function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
        if(nm != 'Data2'){
          compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
          delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */   
          adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
        } else {     
          adder = '';                         /* if data2, there are no calculations to add */
        }
        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
      }
      xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
      ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
      ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
      return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                 /* send tooltip formatting */
      }")) %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime")
```

[image]

> In case your number formatting choices are not as I specified, here are the arguments:

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(value, decimalPlaces, decimalPoint, thousandsSeparator);
```

---

##### Originally Provided:

When you set the series named `data` to the left, you told Highcharts to make the y-axis percentages. However, even if you manipulate the axes to present the actual stock values, Highcharts will still graph the dates on the x-axis and the % on the y-axis.

Your % comp value plotted line will not match that $ y-axis.

I tried to think of a way to articulate better what I mean and why you won't be able to do what you're trying to do... I took stock values and created mock comparison values based on a few ranges (to simulate various zoom settings and how `compare` changes).

You'll see that the stock value might go up, but that doesn't mean that the `compare` value goes up. You'll also see that the values change depending on where you zoom. You would have to have infinite rescaling of the $ axis to align with the % axis.

Here's the code to make the plot and the plot I've mentioned that outlines the issue.

```
library(highcharter)
library(quantmod)

# get stock info
goo <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = F)

# frame data for building comparison values
df1 <- data.frame(dt = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
                                length.out = 300, by = "day"),
                  goo$GOOG.Open[1001:1300]) %>% 
  setNames(c("dt", "val"))

# four sets of comparison values
df1$fromO <- c(NA, ((df1$val - df1[1, ]$val)/df1[1, ]$val)[-1])
df1$from100 <- c(rep(NA, 100), ((df1$val - df1[100, ]$val)/df1[100, ]$val)[101:300])
df1$from200 <- c(rep(NA, 200), ((df1$val - df1[200, ]$val)/df1[200, ]$val)[201:300])
df1$btw150250 <- c(rep(NA, 150), ((df1$val - df1[150, ]$val)/df1[150, ]$val)[151:250], rep(NA, 50))

df1[, 3:6] <- df1[,3:6] * 100   # get % value 

# visualize the issue with plotting comp value but labeling it with the $
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(df1, type = "line", name = "Original Data",
                hcaes(x = dt, y = val)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df1, type = "line", name = "100-300 Days",
                hcaes(x = dt, y = from100), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df1, type = "line", name = "200-300 Days",
                hcaes(x = dt, y = from200), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(df1, type = "line", name = "Between 150-250 Days",
                hcaes(x = dt, y = btw150250), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(opposite = F, title = list(text = "Stock Value ($)")),
                     list(opposite = T, title = list(text = "Comparative (%)")))
```

[image]

Instead of what you proposed, you could plot the dates and *values* and have something like a *tooltip* or label that presents the comparison value. Alternatively, you could plot the data and the comparison value using opposing y-axes. However, if you do that, it won't work with your `data2`.

Why won't that work with `data2`?

A picture answers this a lot faster:

If you have 2 axes, one of the three will essentially be a flat line.

If you have 3 axes, you may be able to align them initially.... check it out:

```
# new range for values axes (align to compare and data2)
low <- min(data$AUM)
high <- max(data$AUM)

# determine 'equivalent to 10' to match scale, using 0-7.57 as old scale
newH <- round(10 * (high - low)/7.57 + low, 0)
newI <- round((newH - low)/5, 0) # new interval of axes

highchart() %>%  # three y-axes with min/max scaling
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Date Compare (%)",
                compare = "percent", yAxis = 1,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data2, type = "line", name = "Data2", compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), yAxis = 2) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(opposite = F, #min = low, max = newH, tickInterval = newI,
                          tickInterval = newI, min = low,
                          breaks = list(breakSize = 1,
                                        from = 0, to = low),
                          title = list(text = "Value ($)")),
                     list(opposite = T, min = 0, max = 10, # used previous plot scale
                          title = list(text = "Compare (%)")),
                     list(opposite = F, min = 0, max = 4000000, # used prev plot scale
                          title = list(text = "Data2"))) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime")
```

[image]

> Here's ONE random zoom... see that the values no longer align.

[image]

> You can see here that the plotting of the `compare` series does not align with the values on the values axes.

[image]

#### Alternative idea

Like a previous Q&A, I suggest you use tooltips to garnish and present the comp values and plot the actual values.

This uses your data and the features you specifically identified in your chart. However, it plots the values, hides the `compare` line, and adds the comp line data to the tooltips for the values.

For `data2`, I used the default tooltip.

[image]

Here's the code to make that plot.

```
highchart() %>%  # three y-axes with min/max scaling
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = F, id = 'dv',
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data, type = "line", name = "Data Values ($)",
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'dv', visible = F, # <-- linked & invisible!
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data2, type = "line", name = "Data2", compare = F,
                hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "Data Values ($)"), opposite = F),
                     list(title = list(text = "Data2"), opposite = T)) %>% 
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c("#336600","#336600","#990000")) %>% # added first color 2 times to account for invisible axes
  hc_tooltip(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(tooltip) {
          /* collect name, x (and format it), y, color, compare value, and % difference */
      nm = this.series.name;
      if(nm == 'Data2') {    /* use standard tooltip for data2 */
       return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
      }
      xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* collect/format date */
      compVal = this.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue; /* 1st val in view */
      col = this.color; y = this.y;                          /* set color and y to vars */
      delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */   
      tooltip = `<span>${xform}<br><hr><b><span style='color:${col};'>`; /* create tooltip */
      tooltip += `● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y.toFixed(0)} (${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;
      return tooltip; /* send back new tooltip */
      }")) %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

Comment: perfect. Didn´t know that you could add an invisible axis to another. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to have the 'split' option in hc_tooltip? So that for each x, you can see both tooltips at the same time

Comment: For me it is also important, since the numbers are quite big, to have a thousand separator. Preferentially the separator is ' '. I´ve tried to format the columns before plotting the graph, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: The code that I use to format the columns: data$AUM <- format(data$AUM,big.mark = " ", scientific = F)

Comment: But it changes the integers to chr

Comment: Do you know a way to change format (add thousand separator as ' ') but keep original class?

Comment: You'll have to format the tooltip values in the call for `formatter`. However, Highcharts is designed to accommodate this type of request: `Highcharts.numberFormatter(value, decimalPlaces, decimalPoint, thousandsSeparator);`  When I declare `y`: `y = this.y;`, you can change this to `y = Highcharts.numberFormatter(this.y,  0, '.', ' ');`. <<- if you copy this from here, the apostrophes may need to be retyped (they may not be recognized as apostrophes in your code).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have the 'split' option? So that for each x, you can see both tooltips at the same time

Comment: I copied the code you provided and retyped the apostrophes, but it didn´t work. The tooltip disappeared

Comment: There were a few things wrong & incomplete regarding that formatting information. I've edited my answer to address the formatting and how to split the tooltips. (Sorry about that!!)

Comment: Everything is working well. Thank you for all your help

Comment: There is another problem. Can you try and remove one series by clicking on that series on the graph? When you put the series back again, the graph goes wrong

Comment: Actually, this only happens to the series that has the compare option: Data Values ($)

Comment: I've added an update to my answer. I wish I had thought to check for that issue! Can you believe that Highcharts JS has stated that the only way to ignore a linked series for this would be to request a feature update? Silly Highcharts. Where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: Can you see my new update?

Comment: I've just noticed that in my code, the column from data and data2 that has dates is called DATA (instead of DATE). In my native language Date is said Data...

Comment: This is a different question. When asking questions, remember they aren't just for you but for anyone with the same question. If you add the new question link as a comment here I will be sure to answer it as soon as I see it.

Comment: Could you please see this new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058533/how-to-add-extra-column-values-to-tooltip