# How to add extra column values to tooltip?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have two datasets: data and data2. Both of these have two columns (one has dates and the other has values).  For each point, I also want to display in the tooltip the number of the week (using the 'week' column from data or data 2).

Datasets:

```
data <- structure(list(DATA = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                          19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                          19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), 
                       AUM = c(32962594L,
                               33213220L, 33278745L, 33482196L, 33591402L, 33591402L, 33660796L, 
                               33810382L, 34172853L, 34264748L, 34032274L, 34216610L, 34416588L, 
                               34462226L, 35308681L, 35429483L, 35456650L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                           -17L), class = "data.frame")

data2 <- structure(list(DATA = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                           19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                           19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), 
                        CUM_SUM = c(0L, 
                                    173080L, 318158L, 504538L, 607304L, 607304L, 771404L, 916984L, 
                                    1153354L, 1292314L, 1381434L, 1708534L, 1937284L, 2035272L, 2817863L, 
                                    3046949L, 3046949L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

View per weeks:

```
#AUM´s:
data <- setDT(data)[order(DATA), .(AUM = AUM[which.max(DATA)], DATA = DATA[which.max(DATA)]), by = .(year(DATA), week(DATA))]  # get last days per week 
data <- data[order(data$DATA),]

# PL:
data2 <- setDT(data2)[order(DATA), .(CUM_SUM = CUM_SUM[which.max(DATA)], DATA = DATA[which.max(DATA)]), by = .(year(DATA), week(DATA))]
data2 <- data2[order(data$DATA),]
```

data looks like this:

[image]

Graph:

```
# Line Plot:
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B' )), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
             formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
               "function(tooltip) {
                        function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;        /* collect color, y, name */
                        compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                        delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */
                        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
                        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                        }
                        xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                        ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
                        ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
                        return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                 /* send tooltip formatting */
                        }")
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

And the plot that results from the code:

[image]

What I want is to have under AUM and under Cumulative NP the week number.
for example (point shown in graph):

```
                                Cumulative NP: 1 708 534 (887.14%)
                                Week Number: 50
                                
                                AUM: 34 216 610 (3.02%)
                                Week Number: 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data that is not part of the plot is not kept in the Highcharts object without telling Highcharts to do so. You can bring in external data to Highcharts, but you don't need to do that here.

Since you want this added to the tooltip `formatter`, which is already in JS, you can just extract the week from the date with JS.

In the tooltip `formatter`, I extract the `x` value, change its class to the JS date type, extract the year to determine the first day of the year, then subtract the number of days between the date and the first day of the year, and finally, divide that value by 7 to get the number of weeks. (Using `ceil`, JS's equivalent to R's `ceiling` when capturing the week number.)

```
# Line Plot:
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, 
                type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, 
                type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B' )), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
             formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
             "function(tooltip) {
                function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                    col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;       /* collect color, y, name */
                    compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                    delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */
                    y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');               /* format y after calc */
             
                    /* determine week number */
                    tx = new Date(pts.x);                         /* create JS formatted date string */
                    fday = new Date(tx.getFullYear(), 0, 1);             /* first day of year for date*/
                    days = Math.floor((tx - fday) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));       /* qty of days since*/
                    weekN = Math.ceil(days/7);                                    /* calc week number */
             
                    adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
                    return `<b>Week Number: ${weekN}<br><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                }
                xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
                ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
                return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                 /* send tooltip formatting */
            }")
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If is not too much to ask, I have a new question related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061328/how-to-order-monthly-dates-on-x-axis

Comment: It's definitely not too much to ask!