# How to order monthly dates on x_axis?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

**Update: Graphs using @Kat's answer**

[image]

[image]

**Originally wrote:**

I have two datasets: data and data2, both with four columns.

Datasets:

```
data <- structure(list(year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
                                2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), 
                       month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                       AUM = c(32679911L, 32346742L, 34420603L, 34420603L, 37224840L, 36470615L, 36470615L, 36368089L, 33122740L, 35996741L, 36653126L, 36047829L),
                       DATA = structure(c(19023, 19051, 19082, 19111, 19143, 19173, 19202, 19235, 19265, 19296, 19326, 19356), 
                                        class = "Date")), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -12L), 
                  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

data2 <- structure(list(year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022),
                    month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                    CUM_SUM = c(-297163L, -552969L, -1186800L, -1323710L, -778329L, -334843L, 96513L, 75763L, 874981L, 1100124L, 1009281L, 961152L),
                    DATA = structure(c(19023, 19051, 19082, 19111, 19143, 19173, 19202, 19235, 19265, 19296, 19326, 19356), class = "Date")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

data looks like this:

[image]

This is the code of my graph:

```
# Line Plot:
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B' )), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
             formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
               "function(tooltip) {
                        function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;        /* collect color, y, name */
                        compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                        delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */
                        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
                        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                        }
                        xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                        ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
                        ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
                        return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                 /* send tooltip formatting */
                        }")
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

That looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to move the x_axis labels to the right. For example, the last points on the graph are values from December 22 and it looks like they are from Jan 23. Therefore, instead of Apr 22, Jul 22, Oct 22 and Jan 23, it should be March 22, Jun 22, Sept 22 and Dec 22.

Comment: With this much of a date spread, 2022-12-30 is placed very accurately. Maybe you want to plot with a month and year format for your results?

Comment: The _easiest_ manner in which to make this happen: add `showLastLabel = F` in `hc_xAxis`.  If this isn't what you prefer, please let me know.

Comment: @Kat, it is not quite that. If you look at the graph, you will see that the ticks on the x_axis mark the start of the month and the points dates are always the end of the month. Therefore, it seems that, for example, the third point's date is April while being 31 of March. I would prefer if the tick was March or Mar, 31 '22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the R code, you'll notice that I've added `dateTimeLabelFormats` for `hour`. That's because when I parse the dates for the last day of the month, JS automatically detects *your time zone*. When I revert the format to a number, JS adjusts for your timezone. This ends up being a few hours different. Since the date is no longer at 0000 (midnight), Highcharts assumes you want the *time* on the x-axis. I've set the date format to *abbreviated month name* & *year*.

> There are methods to start and finish in Greenwich time. The simplest is to adjust the epoch by your timezone. Since my timezone is likely different than yours, which is likely different from whoever looks at your final chart, I've kept it simple. If you are near where the date changes (I think near Hawaii? Between Hawaii and Japan?) It might be worth ensuring the dates start and end in UTC. (Being that far from Greenwich could cause your dates to be an entire day off.)

I've commented out the original call for `hc_xAxis` and added a new call. This utilizes the argument `tickPositioner`. Whatever Highcharts has deemed belongs as a label on the x-axis is collected. This function takes those dates and determines the last day of the preceding month. Finally, it sends new labels for the x-axis back to the chart.

Like other answers I've provided, I've added comments in the JS to identify what's happening. However, if you have any questions or if there is anything wrong/untested, please let me know.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = AUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATA, y = CUM_SUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B' )), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  # hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", showLastLabel = F) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(tickPositioner = htmlwidgets::JS(
    "function() {
        oticks = this.tickPositions;                  /* get the current tick labels */
        giveMe = [];
        for(i = 0; i < oticks.length; i++) {          /* get last day of the month for each data point */
            tht = new Date(oticks[i]);
            tellMe = new Date(tht.getFullYear(), tht.getMonth(), 0);
            giveMe.push(tellMe.getTime());            /* revert date format to proper format for HC */
        }
        return giveMe;                                /* send updated tick labels to chart */
    }"),
    type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b %Y', hour = '%b %Y')) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
             formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
               "function(tooltip) {
                    function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;       /* collect color, y, name */
                        compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                        delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */
                        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip */
                        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');               /* format y after calc */
                        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                    }
                    xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);       /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                    ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);               /* call function to create y-axis tooltips */
                    ttd2 = pref(this.points[1]);
                    return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                                /* send tooltip formatting */
                }")) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used your code and the results are almost the same. However, some months appear in a different format: December appears as 31.Dec,  Jan as 31. Jan and Feb as 28. Feb (instead of Dec 2022, Jan 2022, Feb 2022). I will update my question so that you can see the graphs

Comment: Hmm, I am going to guess that these days landed at midnight. Change the option `dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b %Y', hour = '%b %Y')` to `dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = '%b %Y', hour = '%b %Y', day = '%b %Y')`. Does that fix it?

Comment: @Kat I would like some assistance with debugging please (I'm not very familiar with javascript). In Devtools, I was able to find the `oticks` object and use your code from that point on. (So I did understand that the day parameter of the Date constructor can be used to determine the last day of the previous month by passing the value 0). However, I'm unsure of how to access the object referenced by your code's `this` variable. (so I can have the `tickPositions` property available). Would it be simple to explain that to me? Thank you.

Comment: If you wanted to see everything in `this`, then add `varName = this;` to the JS. Don't assign a variable type to whatever you name this object. For example, instead of `let varName = this;` or `var varName = this;` make sure it's `varName = this;` so it's a global variable. Now when you go into Devtools you'll be able to see everything available to you. If you go down to `prototype` you can see if there are specific Highchart functions available to you for `this`, as well.

Comment: It worked for some but not for every month.

Comment: @Kat, can you please see my new question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100648/how-to-load-and-change-inputs-values-saved-in-csv-file-using-shiny-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the last day of each month, I prefer using the 15th.  Graphically & conceptually, the midpoint is a better representation of the entire month.  My team does this enough that we have a function for it: [`OuhscMunge::clump_month_date()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/OuhscMunge/reference/clump_date.html).

```r
data |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    midpoint = OuhscMunge::clump_month_date(DATA)
  )
```

Output:

```
    year month      AUM       DATA   midpoint
 1: 2022     1 32679911 2022-01-31 2022-01-15
 2: 2022     2 32346742 2022-02-28 2022-02-15
 3: 2022     3 34420603 2022-03-31 2022-03-15
 4: 2022     4 34420603 2022-04-29 2022-04-15
 5: 2022     5 37224840 2022-05-31 2022-05-15
 6: 2022     6 36470615 2022-06-30 2022-06-15
 7: 2022     7 36470615 2022-07-29 2022-07-15
 8: 2022     8 36368089 2022-08-31 2022-08-15
 9: 2022     9 33122740 2022-09-30 2022-09-15
10: 2022    10 35996741 2022-10-31 2022-10-15
11: 2022    11 36653126 2022-11-30 2022-11-15
12: 2022    12 36047829 2022-12-30 2022-12-15
```

The clumping function isn't complicated.  The heart is essentially

```r
lubridate::day(assigned) <- 15L
```

Comment: I need to use the last day of each month, but thank you

Comment: Consider using `DATA` for the analyses and `midpoint` for the graphs.