# How to load and change inputs values saved in csv file using shiny in R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a big shiny app. I will put here a smaller version with no outputs, just inputs. For now I have some inputs in a tab - **Net Production**. I have a second tab - **Home** - where I display all my selected inputs in a table. The ***Save*** action button creates a file called *File (today's date).csv* in a chosen directory ('My Directory') with all the selected inputs. What I need is to make the *Load* button change the inputs saved on the csv file. Basically what I want is to every different user have the option of loading the dashboard with his last saved inputs. If you know a better (and free) way to do this, feel free to share.

This is my reproducible app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
library(stringr)
library(DT)
library(r2d3)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(highcharter)
library(shinymanager)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyr)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(waiter)
library(fresh)
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)



header <- dashboardHeader(title =  'Dash',
                          dropdownMenuOutput('Notifications')
)

dashSidebar <- dashboardSidebar(minified = T, collapsed = T, width = 215,
                                sidebarMenu(
                                  menuItem(text = "Net Production",
                                           tabName = "GraphsTab",
                                           icon= icon('dollar-sign', lib = 'font-awesome'),
                                           badgeLabel = label_date, badgeColor = 'olive'
                                  ),
                                  menuItem(text = "Home",
                                           tabName = "HomeTab",
                                           icon = icon("bar-chart-o")
                                  ),
                                  menuItem(
                                    text = "File Explore",
                                    tabName = "FileExplore",
                                    icon= icon("file-text")
                                  )
                                )
)


dashBody <- dashboardBody(
  
  shinyDashboardThemeDIY(
    ### General
    appFontFamily = "Arial"                             #Application font.
    ,appFontColor = '#000000'                           #Application font colour.
      ,primaryFontColor = '#FFEC8B'                       #Primary status highlight font colour.
      ,infoFontColor = '#FFEC8B'                          #Info status highlight font colour.
      ,successFontColor =  '#FFEC8B'                      #Success status highlight font colour.
      ,warningFontColor =  '#FFEC8B'                      #Warning status highlight font colour.
      ,dangerFontColor =   '#FFEC8B'                      #Danger status highlight font colour.
      ,bodyBackColor =    '#ECF0F5'                       #Main page background colour. --- Cor de Fundo ---  igual a input: buttonBackColor
      
    ### header
    ,logoBackColor =           '#EE7942'                #Logo background colour.
      
    ,headerButtonBackColor =    '#EE7942'               #Sidebar toggle button background colour.
      ,headerButtonIconColor =  '#FFFFFF'                 #Sidebar toggle button icon colour.
      ,headerButtonBackColorHover = '#EB7337'             #Sidebar toggle button background colour: hovered.
      ,headerButtonIconColorHover = '#FFFFFF'             #Sidebar toggle button icon colour: hovered.
      
    ,headerBackColor = '#EE7942'                        #Top header background colour.
      ,headerBoxShadowColor = ""                          #Top header shadow colour.
    ,headerBoxShadowSize = "0px 0px 0px"                #Top header shadow size.
    
    ### sidebar
    ,sidebarBackColor = '#2F4F4F'                       #Sidebar background colour.
      ,sidebarPadding = 0                                 #Sidebar inner padding.
    
    ,sidebarMenuBackColor = "inherit"                   #Sidebar menu background colour.
    ,sidebarMenuPadding = 0                             #Sidebar menu inner padding.
    ,sidebarMenuBorderRadius = 0                        #Sidebar menu shape radius.
    
    ,sidebarShadowRadius = ""                           #Sidebar shadow radius.
    ,sidebarShadowColor = "0px 0px 0px"                 #Sidebar shadow colour.
    
    ,sidebarUserTextColor = '#FFEC8B'                   #Sidebar userbox text colour.
      
    ,sidebarSearchBackColor = '#FFFFFF'                 #Sidebar searchbox background colour.
      ,sidebarSearchIconColor = '#212529'                 #Sidebar searchbox icon colour.
      ,sidebarSearchBorderColor = '#DCDCDC'               # Sidebar searchbox border line colour.
      
    ,sidebarTabTextColor = '#E0FFFF'                    #Sidebar tab font colour.
      ,sidebarTabTextSize = 14                            #Sidebar tab font size.
    ,sidebarTabBorderStyle = "none"                     #Sidebar tab border line style.
    ,sidebarTabBorderColor = "none"                     #Sidebar tab border line colour.
    ,sidebarTabBorderWidth = 0                          #Sidebar tab border line width.
    
    ,sidebarTabBackColorSelected = '#244040'            #Sidebar tab background colour: selected.
      ,sidebarTabTextColorSelected = '#FFFFFF'            #Sidebar tab font colour: selected.
      ,sidebarTabRadiusSelected = "0px"                   #Sidebar tab shape radius: selected.
    
    ,sidebarTabBackColorHover = '#244040'               #Sidebar tab background colour: hovered.
      ,sidebarTabTextColorHover = '#FFFFFF'               #Sidebar tab font colour: hovered.
      ,sidebarTabBorderStyleHover = "none"                #Sidebar tab border line style: hovered.
    ,sidebarTabBorderColorHover = "none"                #Sidebar tab border line colour: hovered.
    ,sidebarTabBorderWidthHover = 0                     #Sidebar tab border line width: hovered.
    ,sidebarTabRadiusHover = "0px"                      #Sidebar tab shape radius: hovered.
    
    ### boxes
    ,boxBackColor = '#FFFFFF'                           #Box background colour.
      ,boxBorderRadius = 5                                #Box shape radius.
    ,boxShadowSize = "0px 0px 0px"                      #String. Box shadow size.
    ,boxShadowColor = ""                                #String. Box shadow colour.
    ,boxTitleSize = 19                                  #Numeric. Box title font size.
    ,boxDefaultColor =  '#FFEC8B'                       #String. Box default highlight colour.
      ,boxPrimaryColor = '#FFEC8B'                        #String. Box primary highlight colour.
      ,boxInfoColor = '#FFEC8B'                           #String. Box info highlight colour.
      ,boxSuccessColor = '#FFEC8B'                        #String. Box success highlight colour.
      ,boxWarningColor = '#FFEC8B'                        #String. Box warning highlight colour.
      ,boxDangerColor = '#FFEC8B'                         #String. Box danger highlight colour.
      
    ,tabBoxTabColor = '#FFFFFF'                         #String. Tab box tab background colour.
      ,tabBoxTabTextSize = 14                             #Numeric. Tab box tab font size.
    ,tabBoxTabTextColor = '#212529'                     #String. Tab box tab font colour.
      ,tabBoxTabTextColorSelected = '#212529'             #String. Tab box tab font colour: selected
      ,tabBoxBackColor = '#FFFFFF'                        #String. Tab box body background colour.
      ,tabBoxHighlightColor = '#EE7942'                   #String. Tab box highlight colour.
      ,tabBoxBorderRadius = 5                             #Numeric. Tab box shape radius.
    
    ### inputs
    ,buttonBackColor =  '#ECF0F5'                       #String. Button background colour. --- Igual a cor de fundo ---
      ,buttonTextColor = '#212529'                        #String. Button font colour.       
      ,buttonBorderColor = '#D3D3D3'                      #String. Button border line colour.
      ,buttonBorderRadius = 5                             #Numeric. Button shape radius.
    
    ,buttonBackColorHover = '#DCDCDC'                   #String. Button background colour: hovered.
      ,buttonTextColorHover = '#212529'                   #String. Button font colour: hovered.
      ,buttonBorderColorHover = '#808080'                 #String. Button border line colour: hovered.
      
    ,textboxBackColor = '#FFFFFF'                       #String. Textbox background colour.
      ,textboxBorderColor = '#D3D3D3'                     #String. Textbox border line colour.
      ,textboxBorderRadius = 5                            #Numeric. Textbox shape radius.
    ,textboxBackColorSelect = '#DCDCDC'                 #String. Textbox background colour: selected.
      ,textboxBorderColorSelect = '#808080'               #String. Textbox border line colour: selected.
      
    ### tables
    ,tableBackColor = '#FFFFFF'                         #String. Table background colour.
      ,tableBorderColor = '#ECF0F1'                       #String. Table border line colour.
      ,tableBorderTopSize = 1                             #Numeric. Table header line size.
    ,tableBorderRowSize = 1                             #Numeric. Table row separator line size.
  ),
  
  tags$style(
    '
        @media (min-width: 768px){
          .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo {
              width: 230px; 
          }
          .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .navbar {
              margin-left: 230px;
          }
        }'
  ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem("GraphsTab",
            
            # h1("BPI"),
            fluidRow(
              column(2,
                     box(id = "Datas_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL,title = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                         dateRangeInput(
                           inputId = "DateRange",
                           label= "Select dates",
                           format= "dd/mm/yyyy",
                           # start = paste0(year(today()),"/01/01"),
                           start = '2022/01/01'
                         ),
                         actionButton(
                           inputId = 'action_1',
                           label = '1m'
                         ),
                         actionButton(
                           inputId = 'action_2',
                           label = '3m'
                         ),
                         actionButton(
                           inputId = 'action_3',
                           label = '6m'
                         ),
                         actionButton(
                           inputId = 'action_4',
                           label = '1y'
                         ),
                         actionButton(
                           inputId = 'action_5',
                           label = 'YTD'
                         )
                     ),
                     tags$head(tags$style('#Datas_box .box-header{ display: none}'))
              ),
              column(2,
                     box(id = "Gup_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                         pickerInput(inputId = "PickerGrupos",
                                     label= "Groups",
                                     choices= c("Dom","I","L","P","VP",'Cl','Pen'),
                                     options = pickerOptions(
                                       `actions-box` = TRUE),
                                     multiple = T,
                                     width = '100%',
                                     selected = c("Dom","I","L","P","VP",'Cl','Pen')
                         ),
                         prettySwitch(inputId = "Stacked_Switch",
                                      label = "NP Stacked", 
                                      status = "default",
                                      fill = TRUE
                         ),
                         tags$head(tags$style('#Gup_box .box-header{ display: none}')),
                         tags$style(".bs-placeholder {color: #212529 !important;}")
                     )
              ),
              column(2,
                     box(id = "Fnd_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                         prettySwitch(inputId = "Union_Switch",
                                      label = "Groups or Profiles",
                                      status = "default",
                                      fill = TRUE
                         ),
                         tags$head(tags$style('#Fnd_box .box-header{ display: none}'))
                     )
              ),
              column(3,
                     box(id = 'Perfis_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:26%;",
                         pickerInput(inputId = 'PickerPerfis',
                                     label = "Profiles",
                                     choices = c('A','D','M','D','I','Outros'),   
                                     options = pickerOptions(
                                       `actions-box` = TRUE),
                                     # style = "btn-primary"
                                     multiple = T
                         ),

                         tags$head(tags$style('#Perfis_box .box-header{ display: none}'))
                     )
              ),
              column(3,
                     box(id = "View_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:26%;",
                         prettyRadioButtons (inputId = "DatesView",
                                             label = "Select view",
                                             choices = c("Days", "Weeks","Months","Years"),
                                             inline = T,
                                             shape = c("curve"),
                                             fill = TRUE,
                                             status = "danger"
                         )
                     ),
                     tags$head(tags$style('#View_box .box-header{ display: none}'))
              )
            )
            
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "HomeTab",
            fluidRow(
              column(2, offset = 5,
                     box(id = 'User_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL,
                         textInput("name", "Name", ""),
                         actionButton(inputId = 'load_button', label = 'Load', icon = NULL, width = NULL),
                         actionButton(inputId = 'save_button', label = 'Save', icon = NULL, width = NULL)
                     ),
                     tags$head(tags$style('#User_box .box-header{ display: none}'))
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              h1("All inputs"),
              tableOutput("show_inputs")
            )
            
    )
  ))

ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(title = 'Dash',
                                        header,
                                        dashSidebar, 
                                        dashBody
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  
  saveData <- function(data) {
    outputDir <- 'My Directory'
    fileName <- paste("File ",as.character(Sys.Date()),".csv",sep = "")
    # Write the file to the local system
    write.csv(
      x = data,
      file = file.path(outputDir, fileName),
      row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE
    )
  }
  
  loadData <- function() {
    # Read all the files into a list
    files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)
    data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
    data <- do.call(rbind, data)
    data
  }
  
  
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
  # Output: Inputs
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  
  AllInputs <- reactive({
    myvalues <- NULL
    newvalues <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(names(input))){
      newvalues <- paste(names(input)[i], input[[names(input)[i]]], sep=":")
      myvalues <- append(myvalues, newvalues)
    }
    myvalues
  })
  
  output$show_inputs <- renderTable({
    AllInputs()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$save_button, {
  
    saveData(AllInputs())
  })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For sharing the dashboard I use  the following code in a **play_dashboard.R** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
rm(list=ls())

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(profvis) 

#options("encoding" = "UTF-8")

## working paths
setwd("My directory")
runApp(host="0.0.0.0",port=82)

#runApp(host="85.88.128.214",port=49152)
```

With the following bat button:

```
@echo off
title esg_dash

"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.1\bin\Rscript.exe" -e "source('My Directory/play_dashboard.R')"

title Command Prompt
pause
```

Comment: How is the app hosted? On the web? An intranet? Have you considered using web cookies? Local cookies are stored in the user's browser. (Instead of using a CSV file... which could easily be opened, modified, renamed, and cause all sorts of issues...)

Comment: I will update my question with the deatils on how we share the dashboard

Comment: As using cookies, I honestly dont know how to do it

Comment: @Kat, really need your help on this. I´ve read the article, https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html , on data storage but did not help.

Comment: Sorry, this slipped off my radar. [See if you can make sense of this](https://github.com/DataScienceScotland/shiny_cookies).

Comment: @Kat, can you please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75163029/r-shiny-how-to-update-output ? It's urgent