# R shiny - How to update output?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have a simple dashboard with three inputs: 'PickerGroups', 'VarToPlot' and 'load_inputs'. The first two are picker inputs and the third is an action button. Since the 'VarToPlot' depends on 'PickerGroups', it is written on the server side. The action button has the purpose of updating the two other inputs with specific values.

This is my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dashSidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = 'Home', tabName = 'HomeTab')
  )
)

dashBody <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'HomeTab',
      fluidRow(
        column(2,
               box(id = "Groups_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                   pickerInput(inputId = "PickerGroups",
                               label= "Groups",
                               choices= c("Domesticos","Imobiliario","Lux"),
                               options = pickerOptions(
                                 `actions-box` = TRUE),
                               multiple = T,
                               width = '100%',
                               selected = c("Domesticos","Imobiliario","Lux")
                   )
               )
        ),
        column(2,
               box(id ='Funds_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                   uiOutput(outputId = "FundosSelection")
               )
        ),
        column(2,
               box(id ='Button_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
                   actionButton(inputId = "load_inputs", label = "Load")
               )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
  sidebar = dashSidebar,
  body = dashBody,
  title = 'Dash',
  skin = 'blue'
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$FundosSelection <- renderUI({
    n <- c()
    if('Domesticos' %in% input$PickerGroups){
      n <- append(n,c('D','O'))
    }
    if('Imobiliario' %in% input$PickerGroups){
      n <- append(n,c('I','m'))
    }
    if('Lux' %in% input$PickerGroups){
      n <- append(n, c('L','x'))
    }
    pickerInput(inputId = "VarToPlot",
                label = "Funds", 
                choices = n,
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = c('D'),
                options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                        dropupAuto = FALSE,
                                        width = "100%")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$load_inputs, {
    n = c('One')
    updatePickerInput(session,inputId = 'VarToPlot', label = 'Funds', selected = c('x'),
                      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                              dropupAuto = FALSE,
                                              width = "100%") )
    updatePickerInput(session,inputId = "PickerGroups", label= "Groups", selected = c('Lux'),
                      options = pickerOptions(
                        `actions-box` = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run the app, you will see that the input 'VarToPlot' will only update after two clicks on the 'load' button. On the first click, PickerGroups beacomes Lux (as pretended) but VarToPlot does not assume the option 'x'. For that, one more click is needed.

Comment: @Kat, could you see this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175476/r-how-to-add-a-limit-to-absolutepanel-from-which-absolutepanel-will-scroll

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this code as is, I couldn't duplicate the issue you've presented. However, when I added an `observeEvent` for the input change to `PickerGroups` I could duplicate the problem.

You've set `VarToPlot` to change under two conditions:

1. if input to `PickerGroups` changes
2. if the button is pressed.

What happens when you press the button?

1. Update `VarToPlot`   <- this is working!
2. Update `PickerGroups` <- this changes `VarToPlot` back to what it was before the button was pressed, because of the FIRST change condition (where the input changes whenever input to `PickerGroup` changes

So why does it work when you press the button again?

1. Update `VarTopPlot`
2. You don't update `PickerGroups` <--- because the settings won't change--- they already match what is being sent via the update

How to fix it?

Like I said, the code didn't do what you had inferred initially, so there are changes to both the user interface and the server here.

1. I've moved `VarToPlot` to the user interface with the initial options (where no `PickerGroup` is selected).
2. I've added a second `observeEvent` to capture when `PickerGroup` changes.
3. I've added a condition to the event that changes `varToPlot` if `PickerGroup` changes. (This condition checks whether conditions for `PickerGroup` match conditions sent by the button.)

The first `observeEvent` has `ignoreInit` set to `TRUE`. This prevents the application from seeing the default selections as an input change. This can be removed. However, this is a good tool to ensure that your events are doing what you expect initially. You can always remove it later.

Here's the code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)        # I added this; didn't run without it

dashSidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(text = 'Home', tabName = 'HomeTab')
  )
)

dashBody <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = 'HomeTab', fluidRow(column(
    2, 
    box(
      id = "Groups_box", width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, 
      style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "PickerGroups",
        label= "Groups",
        choices= c("Domesticos","Imobiliario","Lux","Private","VP",
                   'Clientes Institucionais','Pensoes'),
        options = pickerOptions(
          `actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = T,
        width = '100%',
        selected = c("Domesticos","Imobiliario","Lux","Private","VP",
                     'Clientes Institucionais','Pensoes')
      )
    )
  ),
  column(2,
         box(id ='Funds_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, 
             style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
             # uiOutput(outputId = "FundosSelection"), # <----- removed
             pickerInput(inputId = "VarToPlot",        # <----- added (from server!)
                         label = "Funds", 
                         choices = c('One','Two','Three','1','2','3'),
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         selected = c('One','Two','Three','1','2','3'),
                         options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                                 dropupAuto = FALSE,
                                                 width = "100%")
             )
         )
  ),
  column(2,
         box(id ='Button_box', width = NULL, solidHeader = FALSE, status = NULL, 
             style = "position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:40%;",
             actionButton(inputId = "load_inputs", label = "Load")
         )
  ))))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
  sidebar = dashSidebar, body = dashBody, title = 'Dash', skin = 'blue'
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # when changes to `PickerGroups`
  observeEvent(input$PickerGroups, { # moved the intial `VarToPlot` to UI
     # if first & only selection is 'Domesticos' don't change
    if(!all(input$PickerGroups[1] == 'Domesticos', length(input$PickerGroups) == 1)) {
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = 'VarToPlot',
                        selected = c('One', 'Two', 'Three'),
                        options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                                dropupAuto = FALSE,
                                                width = "100%"))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T) # don't count the default selection as a change
  
  # when button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$load_inputs, {
    n = c('1','2','One')
    updatePickerInput(session,inputId = 'VarToPlot', label = 'Funds', selected = n,
                      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                              dropupAuto = FALSE,
                                              width = "100%"))
    updatePickerInput(session,inputId = "PickerGroups", label= "Groups", 
                      selected = 'Domesticos',
                      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE))
  })
}
```

Comment: I have edit my question since the last version was not clear.  The VarToPlot cannot be written in the ui side, since it´s value depends on the input PickerGroups.