# Percent change with two series

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have two datasets (data and data2) both containing two columns. The column DATE has date values for both datasets.

The datasets:

```
data <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                          19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                          19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), AUM = c(32962594L, 
                                                                                                33213220L, 33278745L, 33482196L, 33591402L, 33591402L, 33660796L, 
                                                                                                33810382L, 34172853L, 34264748L, 34032274L, 34216610L, 34416588L, 
                                                                                                34462226L, 35308681L, 35429483L, 35456650L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                            -17L), class = "data.frame")

data2 <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(19327, 19328, 19331, 19332, 
                                           19333, 19334, 19335, 19338, 19339, 19340, 19341, 19342, 19345, 
                                           19346, 19347, 19348, 19349), class = "Date"), CUM_SUM = c(0L, 
                                                                                                     173080L, 318158L, 504538L, 607304L, 607304L, 771404L, 916984L, 
                                                                                                     1153354L, 1292314L, 1381434L, 1708534L, 1937284L, 2035272L, 2817863L, 
                                                                                                     3046949L, 3046949L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

My objective is to have the percent change option whilst not changing the units of the y-axis. Don´t want to have the y-axis as percentage.
I also want to calculate the percentages in two different ways: for the series data, I want to have the 'normal' percent change option, i.e, if compval is the first value in a view, the percentage change is equal to (y - compVal)/compVal * 100. For the second series, data2, I want the percentage to be in relation to the first value in view of the series data, i.e, for each value y, the percentage is equal to y/compVal * 100 (compaVal being the first value in view of the series data).

This is my try that I think is not optimal:

```
# Line Plot:
highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = list('Combined')) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATE, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATE, y = AUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATE, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
                      var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
                      this.update({visible: shown});
                      return false;
                    }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, type = "line", hcaes(x = DATE, y = CUM_SUM),
                compare = 'percent', linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B' )), opposite = FALSE),
                     list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(split = T, crosshairs = T,
             formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
               "function(tooltip) {
                       function pref(pts) {                     /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
                        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
                        compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
                        compVal2 = compVal
                        delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */ 
                        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip (percentagem)*/
                        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                       }
                       
                       function pref2(pts) {
                       col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
                        compVal = compVal2
                        delta =  y/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */ 
                        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;   /* create remaining string for tooltip (percentagem)*/
                        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
                        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
                       }
                       
        
                        xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);        /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
                        ttd1 = pref(this.points[0]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (AUM)*/
                        ttd2 = pref2(this.points[1]);                /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (CUM NP)*/
                        return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];                 /* send tooltip formatting (DATE, AUM, CUM NP*/
                        }")
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
                            var chart = this; chart.update({
                            chart: {
                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                            }
                            }); 
                            }
                            "))) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

It has to exist a better way of calling the first value in view of the series data (compVal2) in the function pref2.

This is the result:

[image]

Has you can see, 173080/32962594 * 100% = 0.53% and (33213220-32962594)/32962594 * 100% = 0.76%

Comment: You said there has to be a better way. Does that mean that what you have here is calculated correctly? What does your ideal outcome look like? What is it that you want to change from the current state?

Comment: The outcome is correct and there is no change needed. I just think the code isn´t the best. If you look to the tooltip, I save compaVal as compaVal2 in function pref to then use it in function pref2. There must be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything wrong with what you have, but I guess one of the key elements of efficiency, and perhaps the purpose of OOP is to reduce or eliminate redundancy. In other words, code shouldn't be repeated, it should be reused. That was the purpose of the function initially (`pref`), since there were two values that needed to be evaluated every time. If you need to change how the % is calculated between the two, then you could make it conditional.

Here is one method of reducing the very, very small amount of redundancy in your code. I've set the calculation of `delta` to a condition. This is now an argument in the function call. Since you named the functions `pref1` and `pref2`, I've set the conditions to look for either a 1 or a 2.

If anything is unclear, let me know.

```
# Line Plot:
highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = list('Combined')) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM", yAxis = 0, id = "aum_line", data = data, 
                type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATE, y = AUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
        var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
        this.update({visible: shown});
        return false;
      }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "AUM",id = 'aum_line_percent', data = data, 
                type = "line", hcaes(x = DATE, y = AUM), compare = 'percent', 
                linkedTo = 'aum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!)  
  hc_add_series(name = 'Cumulative NP', yAxis = 1, id = 'pl_cum_line', data = data2, 
                type = 'line', hcaes(x = DATE, y = CUM_SUM), events = list(
    legendItemClick = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(e) {
        var shown = this.visible ? false : true;
        this.update({visible: shown});
        return false;
      }"
    ))) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Cumulative NP",id = 'pl_cum_line_percent', data = data2, 
                type = "line", hcaes(x = DATE, y = CUM_SUM), compare = 'percent', 
                linkedTo = 'pl_cum_line', visible = F) %>% # <-- linked & invisible!) 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(title = list(text = "AUM", style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#607B8B')), 
         opposite = FALSE),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE, 
         title = list(text = "Cumulative NP", 
                      style = list(fontSize = "1.5em", color = '#CD8162')))) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = F),enableMouseTracking = T)) %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy') %>%
  hc_colors(c('#607B8B','#607B8B','#CD8162','#CD8162')) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    split = T, crosshairs = T, formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
    "function(tooltip) {
      function tt(pts, wh) {                   /* create y-axis tooltips with this function */
        col = pts.color; y = pts.y; nm = pts.series.name;         /* collect color, y, name */
        if(wh === 1) {
          compVal = pts.series.linkedSeries[0].dataModify.compareValue;  /* 1st val in view */
          delta = (y - compVal)/compVal * 100;   /* compute the comparison value as HC does */ 
        } else {
          delta = y/compVal * 100;                          /* compute the comparison value */ 
        }
        adder = `(${delta.toFixed(2)}%)</span>`;  /* create remaining string for tooltip (%)*/
        y = Highcharts.numberFormat(y, 0, '.', ' ');                 /* format y after calc */
        return `<b><span style='color:${col};'>● ${nm}:</span></b> ${y} ` + adder;
      }
      xform = Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e, %Y', this.x);       /* x-axis tooltip formatted */
      ttd1 = tt(this.points[0], 1);         /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (AUM)*/
      ttd2 = tt(this.points[1], 2);      /* call function to create y-axis tooltips (CUM NP)*/
      return [xform, ttd1, ttd2];              /* send tooltip formatting (DATE, AUM, CUM NP*/
    }")
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS(
    "function() {
      var chart = this; chart.update({
        chart: {
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        }
      }); 
    }"))) %>% hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```